# Accessing a variable that contains MongoDB data outside of a block of code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

In the code below, I'm trying to make it so that the variable "theNames" is available to me in other functions. When I try to access it outside of the current block of code, it comes back as Undefined. I have tried **declaring** the variable outside of the block of code that it resides in currently, but I get the same result. I am not positive, but I suspect that this might be because the MongoConnect code is being executed later.

```
var express = require("express");
    var app = express();
    var port = 3000;
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo");
    var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String
    });
    var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });

    app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
        var myData = new User(req.body);
        myData.save()
            .then(item => {
                res.send("Name saved to database");
                User.collection
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(400).send("Unable to save to database");
            });
    });


    listNames = () => {
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo';
    var theNames;

          MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          if (err) throw err;
          var dbo = db.db("node-demo");
          //Find the first document in the customers collection:
          dbo.collection("users").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            theNames = result;
            console.log(theNames); //This part of the code works as expected.
            db.close();
          });
        });
    }

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
    });
```

Here is how I tried to modify the code to achieve the desired result, but in this case, "theNames" comes back as "undefined".

```
var theNames;

listNames = () => {
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo';

      MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("node-demo");
      //Find the first document in the customers collection:
      dbo.collection("users").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        theNames = result;
        console.log(theNames);
        db.close();
      });
    });
}

console.log(`Here is a list of theNames: ${theNames}`)
```

Comment: `because the MongoConnect code is being executed second` ... close, `theNames` is set to a value asynchronously - but the code you've shown wouldn't have any issue at all, since `theNames` is never referenced outside of the `.toArray` callback - so .. in short, the code you've shown in the question has no problem, so there is no solution

Comment: @jaromandaX Sorry, I don't think my original post explained the problem well. Please see my edits above.

Comment: It as due to the asynchronous propery of nodejs. Try using async await instead of callbacks. Make you listNames function async and return the names result from it. THen do something like this theNames = await listNames(). Then it should work.